# Calling PHP from Python

Tags: php, python

Is it possible to run a PHP script using python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Python [OS module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html). You can run any script by calling

```
os.system('php -f file.php')
```

The issue would be getting return values from PHP to Python here.

Comment: `os.system` should never be used; the `subprocess` module replaces it.

Comment: I did not know that? Why is that ?

Comment: `subprocess` implements many more features and safety checks.  `os.system` works fine if you have a totally static (hardcoded) command, but if you have args, etc... it is a huge security hazard.

Answer (score 14):

You can look into the `subprocess` class, more specifically, [`subprocess.call()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

```
subprocess.call(*popenargs, **kwargs)

subprocess.call(["php", "path/to/script.php"]);
```

Comment: `TypeError`; `subprocess.call` takes a list of strings as its first argument.

Comment: @habnabit Note the square brackets. We're making a tuple with the command followed by the arguments. For example:  
    `cmd="php sandwiches.php --param yum";  
    subprocess.call(cmd.explode());`

Comment: @AWrightIV see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3784156/revisions (also, strings don't have an `explode` method and square brackets make lists, not tuples)