# Python grabbing pages source with PHP in it

Tags: python, python-3.3

I know how to grab a sources HTML but not PHP is it possible with the built in functions?

Comment: Duplicated from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784138/calling-php-from-python

Comment: You can't grab a page's PHP.

Comment: I'm on a windows so I don't think anything on that link would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "grab a sources HTML" I assume you mean opening and reading a web page like this:

```
impor urllib2
urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com").read()
```

Since PHP is rendered on the server side, and the client (you and your python script) have no access to it, there is no way to get at it, in a manner similar to how you would extract HTML from a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

PHP scripts are run server-side and produce a HTML document (among other things). You will never see the PHP source of a HTML document when requesting a website, hence there is no way for Python to grab it either. This isn't even Python-related.