# How can I call PHP script with arguments in python

Tags: php, python-3.x

```py
import subprocess

V1 = 1  #argument1
V2 = 2  #argumeng2

Output = subprocess.call(["bin/sudo -u username /bin/PHP pathtofilename.php V1, V2"])`
```

But my PHP script is not getting executed.

Kindly help.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and apply proper **code formatting**!

Comment: @hc_dev can you able to understand now. I am trying to call PHP script in python by passing arguments to PHP script.

Comment: What did you change? Please prepare your questions: read [ask] and do research before, since your question was already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784138/calling-php-from-python

Comment: I formatted your code, enclosing in 3 backticks. You can also select the code-block and press `CRTL+K`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be in the way you are passing arguments to [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#call-function-trio)

The function's signature is

```
subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None)
```

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
>   of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
>   preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
>   escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
>   names). If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see
>   below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
>   without specifying any arguments.

So your code should be something like this:

```
Output = subprocess.call(["bin/sudo", "-u", "username", "/bin/PHP", "pathtofilename.php", V1, V2])
```

Alternatively it could be

```
Output = subprocess.call(["bin/sudo -u username /bin/PHP pathtofilename.php " + V1 + " " + V2], shell=True)
```

but you should [consider possible security issues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).

Note: If you are on Python 3.5+ consider using [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), especially if you want to capture stdout or stderr with a [CompletedProcess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) instance.